# Tinymce Ajax File/Image Manager

Tags: tinymce

"Ajax File/Image Manager" - very popular TinyMCE plugin and maybe already have someone you have been exposed to the same bug like me and you will help me.

After upload the image or pressing "refresh" button - appears at the bottom of the spacing and incorrect display menu.
How fix this? 
Thanks

[image]